# What to do when app servers go down?

Tags: ios, server, app-store, backend, audio-streaming

I have some apps on the App Store that access servers to stream audio files.
It seems that the servers are down and my apps aren't working.
That's really horrible because am starting to get bad reviews for my apps and people are complaining and saying that apps don't work and don' stream audio.

What should I do in such case?

Comment: Use more reliable servers?  Release an update to your app that gives a better error message?

Comment: Do you know what kind of servers I need for my case.Can you recommend something?

Comment: depends on what you need them for?

Comment: I just need to upload my 128kbs mp3  files to the server then be able the get the links in amy app and stream those audio files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

A. Use more reliable servers.

B. Update your app to use a different server.

C. Have backup servers the app can switch to when the main ones are down.

D. Keep some content local so that if servers are temporarily down, your users can still use that content.

E. Display a message when things aren't working, so your users don't just think your app is bad.

F. Remove it from the app store if it's no longer providing value.

Comment: Thanks Beau Young.Any recommendation for this kind of servers?My apps are down right now and am really in a hurry and don't know what servers to use.Feeling lost!

PS.
I have hundreds of audio files that I need to host and stream.
I have no idea where I can host these files.Does a normal website hosting service can do the job or I need a special kind of server?

My apps gets a lot of request everyday.Around 50K so, the servers should handle the large number of traffic that my apps get and be able to stream the files without gown down.

Comment: You should find out what has caused them to go down in the first place. Perhaps call their customer support? There are literally thousands of providers out there, and its not a topic suitable for stack overflow. I have no idea of your needs, and I wouldn't be the one to ask anyway. I'm just an iOS Developer.